# IntelliJ Idea Spring boot app creates tomcat folder in Temp

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, tomcat

I have a problem with Spring Boot project in IntelliJ Idea - everytime I launch project via IDE Tomcat creates new working directory in appdata\local\temp named 'tomcat.8080.X\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT' where X are random numbers. This should contain predefined subdirectories and uploaded files.

Is there any option to manually set tomcat working folder, for example 'C:\tomcat-work', for not having to go to appdata and manually copy files? I've searched throught settings, project settings, etc, and haven't found anything helpful

Comment: Why aren't you just using the embedded container? Why are you deploying to a tomcat instance in the first place?

Comment: @M.Deinum I've got ready project for furhter development for my purposes. It worked fine, until I had to move it to different pc. I have one WAR packed version and deployed, now I am asking about running project (Shift+F10) from IDE. Every change I make and re-run applicaion, it creates new tomcat folder.

Comment: I don't see why that should be a problem, why are you copying files anyway? Feels like you have things missing in your project (and aren't using Spring Boot properly).

Comment: App handles announcements. It allows to logged users to add/modify and any user with proper link to show all announcements connected with link. Announcements can contain attachments. They should be stored in some folder. Before moving to other PC app started from IDE always used the same folder, f.e. 'c:/folder', now everytime it creates new folder 'appdata/local/temp/tomcat.8080.X/work/Tomcat/localhost/ROOT' and no creating folders into. If I put files manually, it works until I restart in IDE, then it creates new tomcat.8080.Y/work...

Comment: What version of Tomcat is used? What type of run configuration is used in the IDE? If you click the 'Configure' button next to the selected application server in the Tomcat run configuration settings ('Server' tab), you will be presented with a dialog that lets you change Tomcat home and base directories. You can try playing with that.

Comment: If I open 'Run/Debug Configuations' I only have my app name under Sping Boot, on the right is app name, Run on: Local machnie, Java version , boot class name and working directory which I set but nothing appears in it. I don't see any tomcat config. Only when I start app in IDE I've got 'Apache Tomcat/9.0.64' in starting log

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fured out what was wrong. Probably I had some problems deploying to live Tomcat and I've changed path definition for storage service.
I had:

```
Paths.get(context.getRealPath("path", directory);
```

and after changing to:

```
Paths.get("path", directory);
```

it started working as I want to. At least while in development